# Show 10 events per page with paginate in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I'm trying to show 10 events per page in React. I have one view called Events and a component called EventsList. This is the following code:

**src/views/Events/index.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Events from '../../components/EventsList';
import Navbar from '../../components/Navbar';
import { getEvents } from '../../services';
import Spinner from '../../components/Spinner';

const Event = (props) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const EVENTS_PER_PAGE = 10;
  const firstPage = page * EVENTS_PER_PAGE;
  const lastPage = firstPage - EVENTS_PER_PAGE;

  useEffect(() => {
    getEvents()
      .then(function (response) {
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        setError(error);
      })
      .finally(function (response) {
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setItems(data.events?.splice(lastPage, firstPage));
  }, [data]);

  const nextPage = () => {
    setPage(page === data.length / EVENTS_PER_PAGE ? page : page + 1);
    console.log('FIRST SPLICE:', firstPage + 1);
    console.log('SECOND SPLICE:', items.length + EVENTS_PER_PAGE - 1);
  };

  const prevPage = () => {
    setPage(page === 1 ? page : page - 1);
  };

  if (isLoading) {
    return <Spinner />;
  }

  return isLoading ? (
    <Spinner />
  ) : (
    <>
      <Events
        nextPage={nextPage}
        prevPage={prevPage}
        defaultListLength={EVENTS_PER_PAGE}
        defaultPage={page}
        data={items}
      />
      <Navbar title={'Eventos'} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Event;
```

***src/components/EventsList/index.jsx***

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  Container,
  Header,
  EventsText,
  Rectangle,
  SearchHeader,
  FormInput,
  IconContainer,
  PaginateContainer,
  ArrowContainer,
  PaginateText,
  Table,
  TableHeader,
  TableData,
  TableDataText,
} from './styled';
import Button from '../Button';
import Icon from '../Icon';
import Spinner from '../Spinner';

const Events = (props) => {
  if (!Array.isArray(props.data) || !props.data) {
    return null;
  }

  //****** FIN Instancia & function solo para testear EVENTOS, una vez terminado se borra *******
  return (
    <Container>
      <Header>
        <Rectangle></Rectangle>
        <EventsText HeaderTitle>Todos los eventos</EventsText>
        <Link to='/events/signup'>
          <Button primary>Agendar Evento</Button>
        </Link>
      </Header>
      <SearchHeader>
        <EventsText HeaderSubTitle>Buscar eventos de un orientado</EventsText>
        <IconContainer>
          <Icon type='search' width={20} height={20} />
        </IconContainer>
        <FormInput
          // Acá iría funcionalidad del search box, ticket vcampc-23..
          type='text'
          placeholder='Buscar eventos por nombre y apellido del orientado'
        ></FormInput>
      </SearchHeader>
      <PaginateContainer>
        <PaginateText>
          {props.defaultListLength * props.defaultPage -
            (props.defaultListLength - 1)}{' '}
          - {props.defaultListLength * props.defaultPage} de {props.data.length}
        </PaginateText>
        <ArrowContainer circled={'none'} onClick={props.prevPage}>
          <Icon type='arrow-left' height={24} width={24} color='none' />
        </ArrowContainer>
        <ArrowContainer circled={'none'} onClick={props.nextPage}>
          <Icon type='arrow-right' height={24} width={24} color='none' />
        </ArrowContainer>
      </PaginateContainer>
      <Table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <TableHeader>Fecha</TableHeader>
            <TableHeader>Horario</TableHeader>
            <TableHeader>Evento</TableHeader>
            <TableHeader>Participantes</TableHeader>
            <TableHeader></TableHeader>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {props.data &&
            props.data.map((item, i) => {
              return (
                <tr key={i}>
                  <TableData>
                    {item.dateOfEvent.split('-').reverse().join('/')}
                  </TableData>
                  <TableData>{item.hour.slice(0, -3)}hs</TableData>
                  <TableData>{item.eventType}</TableData>
                  <TableData>
                    <TableDataText>
                      {item.mentees &&
                        item.mentees.map((i) => i.name).join(', ')}
                    </TableDataText>
                  </TableData>
                  <TableData>
                    <ArrowContainer DeleteIcon>
                      <Icon type='delete' height={24} width={24} color='none' />
                    </ArrowContainer>
                  </TableData>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Events;
```

**I need to focus on these 2 functions.** I tried a lot of ways but I can't make it work, my logic isn't that good yet so I came here to ask for help :)

Thank you

```
 const nextPage = () => {
    setPage(page === data.length / EVENTS_PER_PAGE ? page : page + 1);
    console.log('FIRST SPLICE:', firstPage + 1);
    console.log('SECOND SPLICE:', items.length + EVENTS_PER_PAGE - 1);
  };

  const prevPage = () => {
    setPage(page === 1 ? page : page - 1);
  };
```

Comment: What isn't working currently?

Comment: Hello Simon! This is my problem right now, I uploaded a gif so you can see it well https://imgur.com/a/rkzNLWh

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I fixed it! Took me a while. The answer is below

```
useEffect(() => {
    getEvents()
      .then(function (response) {
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        setError(error);
      })
      .finally(function (response) {
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const firstPage = page * EVENTS_PER_PAGE;
    const lastPage = firstPage - EVENTS_PER_PAGE;
    setItems(data.events?.slice(lastPage, firstPage));
  }, [data.events, page]);

  const nextPage = () => {
    setPage(page === data.events.length / EVENTS_PER_PAGE ? page : page + 1);
  };

  const prevPage = () => {
    setPage(page === 1 ? page : page - 1);
  };
```